# Can´t create react app using npx create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I´m new to react, but I already created some apps, but today when I tried to create a new one, it just doesn´t work. I´m using Node version v15.6.0 and npm 7.4.0.
My operating system is Windows 10.

My file tree I'm working on: `C: Users\kryst\Documents\test-app\app\package.JSON`

But when I run `npx create-react-app app` in `C: Users\kryst\Documents\test-app` directory, it throws these messages.

```
PS C:\Users\kryst\Documents\test-app> npx create-react-app app

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.2).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\kryst\Documents\test-app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kryst\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-07T09_22_38_962Z-debug.log
```

I´ve already tried `npm cache clean --force` , reinstalling the whole application and restarting the computer.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I´d be grateful for anythig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install -g create-react-app --force
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from **npm 7.0.0** the **npx** binary was [rewritten](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx#compatibility-with-older-npx-versions) and

> the --ignore-existing option is removed. Locally installed bins are always present in the executed process PATH.

So the previously cached binary is always called first, and now we must explicitly state our intentions regarding the package version (just add **@latest** to package name):

```
npx create-react-app@latest app
```

Or if you want to remove old versions from the cache, just clear the **_npx** folder. You can find its location with `npm get cache` command.

Comment: Clearing the contents of the **_npx** folder worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is already in the error logs:

1-you have installed `create-react-app` globally on you machine, so remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

```
  npm uninstall -g create-react-app
  yarn global remove create-react-app
```

2-if you want to create an app just type:

```
npx create-react-app your_app_name
```

this will make `npx` to grab `create-react-app` from npm registry and run it locally without installing it.

Comment: I don't have installed  ```create-react-app``` globally. But even when I run uninstall command and try it again it just doesn't work. Weirdly enough, when I tried to install it globally and then running ```npx create-react-app``` it worked. So I don't know what happened and why, but doing the exact opposite than I've been told solves the problem.